# Github Action and fastlane p12 import failing

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment, fastlane

I'm following up this [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-xcode-applications/installing-an-apple-certificate-on-macos-runners-for-xcode-development) for github actions using fastlane.
As per doc's example, I tried

```
# create temporary keychain
security create-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH
security set-keychain-settings -lut 21600 $KEYCHAIN_PATH
security unlock-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH

# import certificate to keychain
security import $CERTIFICATE_PATH -P "$P12_PASSWORD" -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH
security list-keychain -d user -s $KEYCHAIN_PATH

security import $DEV_CERTIFICATE_PATH -P "$P12_PASSWORD" -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH
security list-keychain -d user -s $KEYCHAIN_PATH
```

But in logs i'm getting this

> ▸ security: SecKeychainItemImport: Unknown format in import.

> ▸ security: SecKeychainItemImport: Unknown format in import.

Hence I'm getting this error:

> No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS Development"
> signing certificate matching team ID "XXXXXXXXX" with a private key
> was found. (in target 'MyCICDAppDemo' from project
> 'MyCICDAppDemo')

Let me know what is wrong.

P.S.: Using manual code signin in xcode. And not want to try with match, sigh etc.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use fastlane? I did something similar recently using this [step by step](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/sign-and-notarize-gha) to sign and notarize a package, that might be a good starting point to investigate. It seems your problem here is with your Developer ID certificates (during the import). Did you use secrets with base64 to get them?

Comment: Yes , i checked the secrets data, i am able to get data, fastlane gives ease to manage several environments as well,.

Comment: I have executed Fastlane command via github actions. Here is the complete blog what i have done: https://dev.to/abhishek9634/deploy-ios-application-to-appcenter-via-github-actions-manual-code-signin-34b9

Answer (score 0):

Here's the gotcha I found. After coping the base64 string with the `pbcopy` command, there will be an extra new line when you paste it in the Github secret panel. Remove the extra new line should solve the issue.

```
base64 -i CERTIFICATE.p12 | pbcopy
```

[image]